# google map API moves toward far marker on every render (seems random)

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, meteor

I made an application that uses the Google Maps API V3. I set a location of

```
myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(22.26, 114.19)
```

which is somewhere in Hong Kong. This is set in "on render" (in Meteor.JS), so that every time you go on that page, it should just go to that location. But the problem is, I deployed it online, and started playing around with the app with my friends. When someone puts a pin outside the screen or far-ish away from the initial location (Hong Kong), every time people render the page again, the map pulls towards that far away pin. Anyone know why and how I can fix this? I do not want to do geo location for now, I will be doing that as a button function later on.

Here is my code:

```
makeModal = (marker, nameObject)->
  google.maps.event.addListener marker, "click", ->
    Crater.overlay "profilepop",
      data:
        nameObject

arrayOfMarkers = []

Template.map.rendered = ->
  if !Meteor.user()
    $('#map-canvas').attr("title", "sign in to add your pin!")
  Crater.dismissOverlay('.crater-overlay')
  GoogleMaps.init
    sensor: true #optional
    key: gmapskey #optional
    # language: "de" #optional
  , ->

myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(22.26, 114.19)
mapOptions =
  zoom: 13
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  center: myLatlng

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions)


google.maps.event.addListener map, "click", (e) ->
  placeMarker e.latLng, map

  updateThis =
    "profile.lat": e.latLng.k
    "profile.long": e.latLng.B
  currentTarget = Meteor.userId()

  Meteor.call 'updateThis' ,updateThis, currentTarget, (error, result) ->

listOfUsers = Meteor.users.find().fetch()


arrayOfMarkers = []
for i in [0...listOfUsers.length]
  if listOfUsers[i].profile.lat != null
    thisLocation = new google.maps.LatLng(listOfUsers[i].profile.lat, listOfUsers[i].profile.long)
    marker = new google.maps.Marker(
      id: listOfUsers[i]._id
      title: listOfUsers[i].profile.name
      position: thisLocation
      map: map
      icon: listOfUsers[i].profile.picturesquare
    )
    mapinfo = "hi"
    name = listOfUsers[i].profile.name
    nameObject = listOfUsers[i]
    contentStr = "<div style='height:auto, width:auto'>#{name}</div>"
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(content: contentStr)
    infowindow.open(map, marker)
    arrayOfMarkers.push(marker)

    makeModal marker, nameObject

console.log arrayOfMarkers


  placeMarker = (position, map) ->
    ##add if statement for people adding forr the first time
    if Meteor.user().profile.lat == null
    else
      oldPin = _.find(arrayOfMarkers, (x) ->
        x.id == Meteor.user()._id
      )
      oldPin.setMap(null)
      oldPin = null
      arrayOfMarkers = _.filter(arrayOfMarkers, (x) ->
        x.id != Meteor.user()._id
      )
    marker = new google.maps.Marker(
      id: Meteor.user()._id
      position: position
      map: map
      animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
      icon: Meteor.user().profile.picturesquare
    )
    mapinfo = "hi"
    name = Meteor.user().profile.name
    picLink = Meteor.user().profile.picture
    contentStr = "<p>#{name}</p>"
    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(content : contentStr)
    infowindow.open(map, marker)
    arrayOfMarkers.push(marker)
    google.maps.event.addListener marker, "click", ->
      infowindow.open map, marker
      makeModal marker, Meteor.user()
```

Comment: You have a bug in your application. It cannot be debugged without seeing code.

Comment: Thank you. I added the code in the edit

Answer (score 0):

put this after you declare your map

`map.setCenter(myLatlng);`